# QDialog::accepted() slot not working

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qdialog

I am trying to implement a signal-slot system for a `QDialog`. After a Google search, I've got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470806/qdialog-exec-and-getting-result-value) on Stack Overflow. That answer looks promising, so I tried to use it. I get no error, but the slot doesn't work. Below is my code:

**newactivity.cpp**

```
// in the QDialog constructor
QObject::connect(this->ui.createBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(accept()));
QObject::connect(this->ui.cancelBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(reject()));

void newActivity::accept() {
    QDialog::accept(); // to close the dialog and return 1
}
void newActivity::reject() {
    QDialog::reject(); // to close the dialog and return 0
}
```

**schedule.cpp**

```
void Schedule::on_actionNew_Activity_triggered() {
    newActivity *newActivityWnd = new newActivity(this, Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint);
    newActivityWnd->exec(); 
    QObject::connect(newActivityWnd, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(on_activityCreated()));
}

void Schedule::on_activityCreated() {
    this->ui.timeLine->hide();
}
```

Here is my dialog:

[image]

Nothing happens when I press the <kbd>Create</kbd> button on `New activity` dialog. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you reorder the code in schedule.cpp as:

```
void Schedule::on_actionNew_Activity_triggered() {
    newActivity *newActivityWnd = new newActivity(this, Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint);
    QObject::connect(newActivityWnd, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(on_activityCreated()));
    newActivityWnd->exec(); 
}
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah. It solves the problem. This was the last thing that would have came to my mind... :))

Comment: Glad to help, actually this happens because of the eventloop started by `exec()` which no more moves to next lines of code I suppose.I will leave a link down here when I will find corresponding explanation. Don't forget to mark answer as accepted if your problem got solved :P