# Qt Signals and Slots between Forms

Tags: qt

How do I connect a Signal from a form to a Slot in another form?  In other words I have a value that I am manipulating in a dialog.ui file that I want to emit to a slot that changes the value in the main application.

Comment: The standard method is to pull values out of a dialog after the user dismisses it. You provide an accessor and pull the values you need before disposing of the dialog.

Comment: I am new to Qt. Exactly what syntax do you use to do that. I feel as though I have tried many ways to no avail.

Comment: Here's one solution which does use signals; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470806/qdialog-exec-and-getting-result-value

Comment: What good is it to downvote a Question if a comment as to why it is downvoted doesn't accompany it? How do I fix whatever issue is causing people to down vote a Question if I don't know whats wrong with the Question itself? School would have been quite difficult if Teachers just told you you were wrong but never told you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to controller of the main GUI and connect both of them , like :

```
    connect(form1,SIGNAL(increment()),form2,SLOT(manipulate()));
```

don't forget to use emit in the first form.