# Qt5 Get response from child dialog

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

In my Qt5.7 program I have a password security. At some situations I want to ask user for password. I want to do it by separate QDialog. This dialog checks if password are good. And here is a problem. How Can I check from parent Dialog if authorisation was positive?

My dialog:

[image: Sorry for editiong, I haven't transalted it yet]

And code to show dialog:

```
PasswordGet pass;
pass.setWindowFlags(Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
pass.setModal(true);
pass.exec();
```

To sum up, I want to know if user clicks Cancel (dialog just close), or clicks Authorize (password was good, and dialog close)

How can I do this? I don't want to make new global bool and check from parent dialog if bool == 1, it's not secure.

Comment: Is PasswordGet a subclass of QDialog?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QDialog exec() and getting result value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470806/qdialog-exec-and-getting-result-value)

Comment: @demonplus thank you for linking this thread, it helps me with solving my problem. Now my thread could be duplicate :/

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use the password dialog that Qt already provides. If you need examples of how to use Qt dialogs see their excellent example here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-standarddialogs-example.html

You would want to use [`QDialogEdit::getText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#getText) with a [`QLineEdit::EchoMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum) of `QLineEdit::Password`. If you're expecting the user to enter: `QString password` Then your code will look something like this:

```
bool ok;
QString text = QDialogEdit::getText(this, tr("Authorization"), tr("Password:"), QLineEdit::Password, QString(), &ok);

if(ok && text == password) // Success, do you're action here
```

Comment: Thank you for idea, but I have solved my issu another way.

Comment: @KamilKlecha If possible you should post your solution here and accept it to benefit anyone coming after you who may also be struggling with the same issue!