# QDialog: need pressed button or return value

Tags: c++, qt

i'am searching a easy way to get the pressed button from QDialog widget.
(all buttons finished the dialog after a pressed event, Many Buttons). this way:

```
MyDialog *ptrMyDialog = new MyDialog;
ptrMyDialog->exec(); // blocked til finished 
// ??? 
QAbstractButton * btn = ptrMyDialog->Function_I_Need();
// or. I only need a spezific return value, set by button. e.g
auto retValIneed= ptrMyDialog->exec();
```

Any hint will be helpful

regards Lars

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470806/qdialog-exec-and-getting-result-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QDialog exec()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) already returns whether the dialog was [accepted](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accepted) or [rejected](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#rejected). If the distinction between these two is not sufficient, since you already have a custom class you can easily implement such behaviour yourself.

Any button already calls one of the functions which closes the dialog, so you can simply store which one was pressed within a member of the class and retrieve that value using the method you desire.

A different possibility would be to overload `exec()`, call the base class implementation within it and return your custom member which stores what button was pressed as before directly.

Comment: hi and thanks. i overload the exec() method. it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

You will have call the [setResult(int r)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#setResult) method when handling the buttons in MyDialog, then *result()* will give you the according value (and probably also *exec()*). For details how this is done you could check the *QMessageBox* implementation, since there *exec()* returns the actual button ID.

Comment: hi and thanks. i tried the setResult/result mechanism without  success.  how i should close the dialog in buttonhandler. i tried setResult/close ; setResult/finished ; setResult/done. seems there only to states 0 & 1

Comment: In *QMessageBox* a button ID is passed to setResult, see [qmessagebox.cpp:1356](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qmessagebox.cpp.html), you should probably do something similar.